# Check user activity status - Android

Tags: android

How can I check if the user is active or not?

I've tried some on.. methods and arrived at this which works:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {

        userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userID).update("active", true);

    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {

        userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userID).update("active", true);

    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {

        userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userID).update("active", false);

    }

}
```

This is in the MainActivity. I don't know if I should use the onStart method. Anyway, I just want to change the activity status of the user if he has switched apps from the recent apps button or has done anything else outside the app. Cause if he had done so, the activity remains true.

And if the methods mentioned above are wrong please correct them.

Comment: You need to create one BaseActivity and all other activity should be override with BaseActivity.When on callbase of onResume() -> update("active", true) and on callbase of onPause()-> update("active", false)

Comment: @HardikBambhania Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create **BaseActivity.java** where you can send user online status.

**BaseActivity.java**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            userID = firebaseUser.getUid();
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userID).update("active", true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            userID = firebaseUser.getUid();
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userID).update("active", false);

        }
    }
}
```

E.g now you have other activity like ActivityOne,ActivityTwo and ActivityThree then

**ActivityOne.java**

```
public class ActivityOne extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**ActivityTwo.java**

```
public class ActivityTwo extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**ActivityThree.java**

```
public class ActivityThree extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this for a chatting app. When the user is offline, there will be a last seen message showing. The code is working perfectly. But when switching activities, the value is set to ```false``` and then to ```true``` fast (I think this is due to the ```onResume``` and ```onPause``` methods. However, when the user enters the **ChatActivity** with the chatUser, the value of the 'active' field is true but there is the last seen message shown. And this is done using the ```addSnapshotListener``` method. Do you have any idea how can do this perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

Then functions you need to use are the onStart() and onStop() on the main activity. Also, suggest rename your "active" variable as "online".

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {

        userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userID).update("online", true);

    }

}
```

Then we need to set it to `false` when the user exits. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();

    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {

        userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userID).update("online", false);

    }

}
```

I recommend not using the onDestroy() at all. Then you can access it in the database easily. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried using these two, but when another activity is started, the value is set to false.

Comment: You know right, that you don't have to include this function anywhere else in the other activities?

Comment: I mean I though what you needed to do, what I was recommending was what @Hardik said, but I though you already knew not to include this code in other activities.